# SQL IF/CONDITIONAL Querty

Tags: sql, informix

Is it possible to structure a query that will display a static value for a row based on a column?

EG.

In INFORMIX, the syscolumns type is returned as an integer. I would like to have it print out the table type as a string rather than an integer.

For example, when I run a simple query to get the system tables

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TABID < 100
```

I get

```
    colname   tabid  colno  coltype collength
------------------------------------------------
    tabname     1      1      13       128
```

WHERE coltype = 13 corresponds to VARCHAR

So my original query would give me

```
COLNAME    COLTYPE
col1       0
col2       1
...
```

But I want it to be returned as

```
COLNAME     COLTYPE
col1       CHAR
col2       SMALLINT
...
```

Is such a thing possible to do in a single query?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read the question twice, and don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Can you give sample schema, sample data, and expected results please?

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN COLTYPE = 0  THEN 'CHAR' ELSE 'SMALLINT' END AS COLTYPE FROM ?`

Comment: Why don't you join to the table you looked at to figure out that coltype = 13 is varchar?

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm not aware of a table that has that information. That's simply what I'm pulling from the reference guide http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst41.htm

Comment: If this is a one time job, a rather long case statement will get the job done.  Otherwise, create and populate a table, preferably in such a way that it's avaialable to all applicable databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMN, 
       CASE
         WHEN COLTYPE = 0 THEN 'CHAR'
         WHEN COLTYPE = 1 THEN 'SMALLINT'
         ELSE CAST(COLTYPE AS VARCHAR)
       END as COLTYPE
FROM MyTable
```

So, for example, with this table:

```
  COLUMN     |    COLTYPE
-------------+--------------
   col1      |       0
   col2      |       1
   col3      |       2
```

The result would be:

```
  COLUMN     |    COLTYPE
-------------+--------------
   col1      |     CHAR
   col2      |   SMALLINT
   col3      |      2
```

However, if `coltype` maps to an `id` or similar in another table, it would make more sense to join to that table, like:

```
SELECT MyTable.COLUMN, SecondTable.COLUMNNAME
FROM MyTable
JOIN SecondTable ON MyTable.COLTYPE = SecondTable.COLTYPE
```